# ag-grid cellrenderer: adding html tags to cells but not in the template but as return values of a function

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have recently found ag-grid and am trying to integrate it into an existing angular project of mine. Currently, I am trying to figure out how custom cell renderers work. In the end, I want to put (somewhat) complex HTML statements in some cells depending on the cell value. But for the moment i just want to wrap the contents (simple strings) in <b></b> tags.

Basically, I have done all the essential stuff, namely:

- created a basic-render.component.ts,
- added the needed lines to the app-module.ts
- and added all the relevant ag-grid stuff to the component that is using/showing the ag-grid.

This all worked fine, also the cellrenderer is applied to the cells! 
But the problem is: the <b> tags are not interpreted as HTML, but as strings and are displayed as such!

my basic-cellrendeer.component.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AgRendererComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'basic-cell',
    template: `{{valueBasic()}}`
})
export class BasicRenderer implements AgRendererComponent {
    private params:any;

    agInit(params:any):void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        this.params = params;

        return true;
    }

    private valueBasic():string {
        return "<b>" + this.params.value + "</b>";
    }
}
```

i have this in my app.component.ts

```
  columnDefs = [ 
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', cellRenderer: 'BasicRenderer'},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
  ];
```

As I said the table is shown correctly, but the first column looks like this: '<b>value1</b>', '<b>value2</b>' and so on...

But interestingly, when putting the  tags into the template like this, it works:

```
template: `<b>{{valueBasic()}}</b>`
```

But that is no real solution because in the end, when everything works, I want to include more complex HTML statements, which need to be returned by a function like I tried to achieve here.

Comment: Can you give an example of the more complex html you need to return, and why does the html need to be returned from a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render **OWN** (*out of angular compilation*) HTML, you have to wrap it

case 1:
`[innerHtml]="valueBasic()"`

case 2:
`[innerHtml]="{{valueBasic()}}"`

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation) you can read more about angular interpolation

**UPDATE**

To make `styles` works you have to create another pipe

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

and can use it like :

```
<div [innerHtml]="valueBasic()| safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: that (template: `[innerHtml]={{valueStatus()}}`) does not work. Now i have [innerHtml]=<b>value</b> inside the cells

Comment: `<div [innerHtml]="{{valueStatus()}}"></div>`

Comment: ok this kind of works. I get the HTML but when I add CSS stylesheets, via style="" or class="" and even via [ngStyle] and [ngClass] all of it gets stripped and the console logs:    WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Answer (score 0):

We can use a CellRenderer function to Create a custom HTML template for each cell as given below. I had a link under my tooltip and I did not want to show the href of the  anchor tag for which I have used innerHTML.

```
{
      //field: 'TOOL_TIP',
      headerName: 'Tooltip',
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      cellRenderer: params => {
        var a = document.createElement('div');
        a.innerHTML = params.data.TOOL_TIP;
        return a;
      },
      tooltip: (params) => '' + params.value
    }
```